# How do I get a segment of my code to repeat under specific a specific circumstance python?

Tags: python

I am trying to get my game to repeat the part of my code where it asks for what attack you want to do after someone writes help. I belive I could just copy and paste that part of the code after my if statement, but that would be a very finite solution. The current way I am doing it, by using a while loop does not work because the thing that would change the while loop is within a different indentation segment of the code. any help here is appreciated.

```
def AttackSet():
    NewMH = MH
    while True:
        print('your attack options are: smash, hit')
        print('type help to see more info about attacks or ')
        chosenAttack = input('choose your attack by writing the first letter of the attack you choose: ')
        #choosing attack
        smash = [15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
        sm = random.choice(smash)
        def HelpWrite():
            print("Info:")
            print("Smash has as lower max attack, but has a higher chance of max attack")
            print("Hit has a much higher max attack, but has a very low chance of getting it")
            print("   ")
        def SmashAttack():
            print("Smash does", sm, "attack")
            print("monster's new health: ", NewMH)
        hit = [10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
        hi = random.choice(hit)
        def HitAttack():
            print("Hit does", hi, "attack")
            print("monster health: ", NewMH)
        if chosenAttack == "h" or chosenAttack == "H":
            NewMH = MH-hi
            HitAttack()
        if chosenAttack == "s" or chosenAttack == "S":
            NewMH = MH-sm
            SmashAttack()
        if chosenAttack == "help" or chosenAttack == "Help":
            HelpWrite()
```

Comment: What is `MH-hi`?

Comment: You shouldn't be defining your methods inside the while loop because 1) It looks bad and is more difficult to read 2) it comes at a performance cost.

Comment: A simpler way to write `if chosenAttack == "h" or chosenAttack == "H":` is just `if chosenAttack.lower() == "h"`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ambiguities in your code, But I'll try my best to help you. first of all:

- you shouldn't write functions inside `while` loop.
- you can replace `chosenAttack == "h" or chosenAttack == "H"` with `chosenAttack.lower() == "h"`.

maybe your problem get solved if you use `continue` and add another statement for exiting the loop:

```
import random

def HitAttack():
    print("Hit does", hi, "attack")
    print("monster health: ", NewMH)

def HelpWrite():
    print("Info:")
    print("Smash has as lower max attack, but has a higher chance of max attack")
    print("Hit has a much higher max attack, but has a very low chance of getting it")
    print("   ")

def SmashAttack():
    print("Smash does", sm, "attack")
    print("monster's new health: ", NewMH)


def AttackSet():
    NewMH = MH
    while True:
        print('your attack options are: smash, hit')
        print('type help to see more info about attacks or ')
        chosenAttack = input('choose your attack by writing the first letter of the attack you choose: ')
        #choosing attack
        smash = [15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
        sm = random.choice(smash)
        hit = [10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
        hi = random.choice(hit)
        if chosenAttack.lower() == "h":
            NewMH = MH_hi
            HitAttack()
            continue

        elif chosenAttack.lower() == "s":
            NewMH = MH_sm
            SmashAttack()
            continue

        elif chosenAttack.lower() == "help":
            HelpWrite()
            continue

        elif chosenAttack.lower() == 'exit':
            break

AttackSet()
```

**I can't test this code cause of ambiguities** like `NewMH`, `hi`, `MH`. Also, I can see `MH-hi` in your code. this kind of naming isn't acceptable for python. if `MH-hi` is the name of a variable, you should replace it with `MH_hi` as I did.

---

### Appendix

in case of testing the script, I have to remove unknown variables that you didn't declare in your question, for example: `NewMH`, `hi`, `MH`, ... . so :

```
import random

def HitAttack():
    print("Hit does attack")
    print("monster health: ")

def HelpWrite():
    print("Info:")
    print("Smash has as lower max attack, but has a higher chance of max attack")
    print("Hit has a much higher max attack, but has a very low chance of getting it")
    print("   ")

def SmashAttack():
    print("Smash does attack")
    print("monster's new health:")


def AttackSet():
    while True:
        print('your attack options are: smash, hit')
        print('type help to see more info about attacks or ')
        chosenAttack = input('choose your attack by writing the first letter of the attack you choose: ')
        #choosing attack
        smash = [15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
        sm = random.choice(smash)
        hit = [10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
        hi = random.choice(hit)
        if chosenAttack.lower() == "h":
            HitAttack()
            continue

        elif chosenAttack.lower() == "s":
            SmashAttack()
            continue

        elif chosenAttack.lower() == "help":
            HelpWrite()
            continue

        elif chosenAttack.lower() == 'exit':
            break


AttackSet()
```

This worked fine as you wish. continues to get input from the user till the user type 'exit'.

Answer (score 0):

You should move all you functions def outside the while loop.

then you can use something like If input = 'help' then call function write help.